# "IIS Manager Permissions" icon missing from Windows Server 2019 IIS

Tags: iis, webdeploy

I wanted to setup web deployment from Visual Studio into an AWS EC2 instance.

First, I launched a EC2 instance of **Windows Server 2019 Base**. I added IIS and ASP.NET Windows features. Then I downloaded **Web Deploy 3.6 msi** and chose to install "**complete features**".

After that, I started IIS manager, and went to "**Default web site**". Under the "**Management**" group, I expect to see a "**IIS Manager Permissions**" icon, but it was not there. I need it to enter the user name/password, which will be used by my Visual Studio to connect to this IIS.

Where did I get it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS Manager Permissions is only visible if you enabled Management Service role service,

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/remote-administration/configuring-remote-administration-and-feature-delegation-in-iis-7#configuring-remote-connections-in-iis-manager

Comment: Thank you Lex! Now the "IIS Manager Permissions" icon is shown. I then proceeded to setup web deploy following https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later. On step 9, "Right-click the site that you are configuring, point to Deploy", the "Deploy" context menu item is not there. What is missing this time?

Comment: @SillyDude go back to this step https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy-on-iis-80-or-later#using-the-web-deploy-installer-to-install-web-deploy Were you able to select all features to be installed? If you didn't enable all features, then some functionality can be missing.

Comment: I worked out - I had to uninstall Web Deploy then install it. Then the "Deploy" context menu will appear when I right click the site on IIS.